# SceneKit – AVPlayer material crash

Tags: iphone, swift, avfoundation, scenekit, ios11

I'm using a video as the material for an SCNNode:

```
geo.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = AVPlayer(url: url)
```

This works ***fine*** on most iOS devices but crashes on the older iPhone 5s with the following error:

```
-[MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:], line 781: error 'MTLTextureDescriptor has invalid pixelFormat (520).'
-[MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:]:781: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has invalid pixelFormat (520).'
```

Is there a fix/workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a ***hardware issue*** of iPhone 5s. Try to use a `SKVideoNode` as a workaround. SpriteKit's objects are much "lighter" for iPhone 5s.

```
var videoNode: SKVideoNode? = {

    guard let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", 
                                                ofType: "m4v") else {
        return nil
    }    

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

    return SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
}()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So this works, apart from SKVideoNode brings a new problem- if you close the app and then reopen it from the background, the video now begins to autoplay. :/

Comment: In the beginning use `var player: AVPlayer? = nil`. Or in the end, after `play.pause()` use a string `player = nil` to deallocate AVPlayer (`var player: AVPlayer?`).